# Duplicated .gdoc files

Tags: google-drive

If you have, say 3, duplicates of a `.gdoc` file locally (they're just reference files, I know). Then you delete 2 of them, and you specifically get told by your Google Drive app that if they are removed from Google Drive Trash, then the document online will be deleted.

Does that mean that if you make a duplicate of a `.gdoc` file (a reference), you can never delete it again without losing the one document that's stored online? The one document they're all pointing to?